# When was package last updated?

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2

How do I find out when a certain package was last updated as part of a `sudo yum update` run?

System: Amazon Linux AMI, based on CentOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `yum history` and its variants:

```
yum history packages-info openssl
```

will give you each transaction that included the `openssl` package.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively and not nearly as comprehensive as the answer above, but with the advantage that the rpm command doesn't require root privileges in this case, would be:

```
rpm -qa --last <package>
```

omitting the package name will list the install date of all currently installed packages instead of a specific package.